# Detecting that a button/submit returning false

Tags: javascript

I have this simple javascript:

```
window.onclick = function test(e) {
    if(e.which == 1)
    { if(e.target.type == 'submit')
      {  // Actions here
      }
    }
}
```

And I have a (submit) button somewhere on the page which has attribute onclick
that returns true on certain conditions and returns false on others.

Is there a way detect when the button/submit button is pressed,

- If it is successfully executing all the onClick/onSubmit/onChange attributes attached to it?
- Or, if it fails and terminated by any conditions? (in my case, the return false statement)

Comment: You can use the callback of the button function (or submit success function) to trigger an alert/set a variable/flip a boolean/put a message in the console.  Check the output and you'll know what happened.

Comment: Anyway you can give an example of the code of how to achieve this in regard to the piece of code I displayed? For example: e.target.callback = true? (which I'm sure will not work ^^)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution (by declaring a globally-scoped javascript variable) -

```
<input type="submit" onclick="SubmitOnClick();" id="myBtn" value="Click" />
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var g_isSuccessfulSubmit = null;

    window.onclick = function test(e) {
            if(e.which == 1)
            {
                if (e.target.type == 'submit')
                {
                    var isSuccessful = g_isSuccessfulSubmit;
                    g_isSuccessfulSubmit = null;
                    // Actions here
                }
            }
        }

    function SubmitOnClick() {
        var isSuccessful = false;
        //if (successfully executing) 
        //{
        //    isSuccessful = true;
        //}

        g_isSuccessfulSubmit = isSuccessful;
        return isSuccessful
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The downside is that I might have to rewrite all the codes regarding these onclick/onchange/onsubmit attributes. Preferred not to do that....